# Not able to debug Jasmine Unit Tests when building using angular cli

Tags: debugging, webstorm, angular-cli

We recently started building our application using Angular-Cli. As part of that all our configs are changed. However now, we cannot debug any of our tests directly from WebStorm. A typical directory in our project looks like

```
Root
-Node_Modules
-dist
-src
-tmp
-other json files.
```

As you may know, with angular-cli tsc will generate corresponding js files in dist folder. Our spec files are right along with corresponding ts file.

Now, I am trying to debug a test in WebStorm. it does not even execute my tests and none of my breakpoints are hit in TS file. (I can still debug in browser using js files from dist folder)

Comment: What WebStorm version do you use? Can you please try WebStorm 2016.2.1 EAP: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/07/webstorm-2016-2-1-eap-162-1447/ The problem with Karma debugging that was introduced in WS 2016.2.0 was fixed. That might help.

Comment: it still doesn't work. There is an improvement where it now at least execute tests in debug mode, however, 1) it is very slow 2) it still doesn't hit any of the breakpoints.
In console window I can see various 404 errors where karma server not able to find js.map files. It is happening only for js.map but thats what breaking debug. The files are there but it just adds ..%5C..%5c..%5C to path for no reason and complains that they are not there.
Another error that I see is throwing "AccessDeniedException" for zone.js under node modules.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try. We're continue investigating. The exception will be fixed in WebStorm 2016.2.1 stable: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22522
Here's a more general issue to follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22512 Sorry for the inconvenience.